# What does really happen on POST _cache/clear?

Tags: elasticsearch

Sorry if my question is trivial as I'm not familiar with ES.

How should I interpret `query_cache` values if I [clear cache](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.2/indices-clearcache.html) between [stats](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_cluster_stats.html) calls?

```
// GET _cluster/stats
{
    ...
    "indices": {
        ...
        "query_cache": {
            "memory_size_in_bytes": 229449664,
            "total_count": 19146885372L
            "hit_count": 18430071,
            "miss_count": 19128455301L,
            "cache_size": 4101,
            "cache_count": 126089,
            "evictions": 121988
        }
    ...
    }
    ...
}

// POST _cache/clear

// GET _cluster/stats
{
    ...
    "indices": {
        ...
        "query_cache": {
            "memory_size_in_bytes": 0,
            "total_count": 19146885372L
            "hit_count": 18430071,
            "miss_count": 19128455301L,
            "cache_size": 0,
            "cache_count": 126089,
            "evictions": 121988
        }
    ...
    }
    ...
}
```

As you can see `memory_size_in_bytes` and `cache_size` have been zeroed. What does that mean? Why `cache_count` has not been changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a short explanation for each values:

- `memory_size_in_bytes` is the amount of memory occupied by queries in the cache
- `total_count` is the total number of lookups in the cache (= `hit_count` + `miss_count`)
- `hit_count` is the total number of cache HIT
- `miss_count` is the total number of cache MISS
- `cache_size` is the total number of queries currently in the cache
- `cache_count` is the total number of cache lookups so far (= `cache_size` + `evictions`)
- `evictions` is the total number of queries that have been evicted from the cache

So when you clear the cache, the only thing that you can really clear is the memory (i.e. `memory_size_in_bytes`) and the number of cached queries (i.e. `cache_size`). It doesn't really make sense to clear the other values as they are just counters.

Comment: Very much appreciated